# ¿Cómo guardar token, para utilizarlo mientras este activo en java?

Tags: java, spring, tokens

Buen días Estimados.

Estoy consumiendo una API la cual me provee de un token de autorización, quisiera saber como puede guardar este token para ser utilizado mientras este vigente, aclaro que no puedo utilizar una base de datos.

He pensado utilizar un archivo .properties en el cual sobre-escribiria este token pero no se si es la opción adecuada.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Puedes guardarlo en sesión. Lo que indicas de un archivo, qué diferencia tiene con usar una BD para tu implementación? Es persistirlo en alguna parte, igual. Más allá de estos comentarios, tu pregunta busca opiniones, no tiene ningún contexto ni problema que podamos reproducir, por lo que muy posiblemente termine cerrada. Revisa si puedes replantearla a un problema específico.

Comment: Podrías consultar por el token cada vez que se intente utilizar, si esta activo se utiliza el mismo y si esta inactivo se consulta por otro. Si no puedes usar BD podrías probar con sqlite. O guardarlo en una variable global mientras se mantenga la sesión.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Efectivamente, utilicé una variable de clase(static) y consulto el token solo una vez y lo guardo para todas las consultas de la sesión.